# Setup MinGW for creating OpenGL context in WINAPI?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, opengl

I've been trying to setup MinGW to work with C and WINAPI to create OpenGL projects. How to I download, or otherwise get, the OpenGL headers and libraries?

I've already read that I can use `#include <gl/glu.h>`. I tried that and got some errors like `"include glu.h" not found`, and so on. I tried downloading these .h files and putting them inside the Include/GL folder, but now I get errors like `Undefined reference to... bla bla` when I link, even when I add linker options like `-lopengl32 -lglu32`, etc.

How can I start with C, WINAPI and OpenGL environment?

What do I need to get, download or set up to create OpenGL projects with C and WINAPI?

My OS is Windows 10 64 bit.
My MinGW version is 4.9.2-tdm64-3/4.9.2-tdm3

Comment: I've tried to remove a lot of the repetition from this question. Since that was a relatively big edit, I'll remind you that just because I have a big number next to my name doesn't mean I know any better than you, and it doesn't mean I have any authority, and if you disagree with my edit you're free to undo it.

Comment: @immibis: Too bad the question still is off-topic. It is either - asking for off-site resources/a tutorial or too broad.

Comment: @Olaf No, I'm not asking for a tutorial, I'm asking for WHAT do I need to use OpenGL in WINAPI.

Comment: What are you getting undefined references to, when you use `-lopengl32` and `-lglu32`?

Comment: @immibis
Almost any gl.h and glu.h functions lol
glBegin, glEnd, color, vertex functions, etc.
According to what I've found, it's because I'm using a different (Newer or older) header than the .lib and DLL in system. My question is, where can I find what I need to build OpenGL projects? I already tried in opengl wiki, but oficial link is fallen lel
I tried searching the file name from the wiki on internet, found it but not working either with headers, libs and dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I need to get, download or set up to create OpenGL projects with C and WINAPI?

In theory: *nothing!*

OpenGL-1.1 is part of the Win32 ABI, i.e. the contract between the OS and compilers how things work together and what must be supported at a minimum for a development environment to be a fully suitable platform SDK.

MinGW normally brings the necessary development resources (headers, libraries, linker definition files) by default. So I'd start by double checking, that the compiler is installed properly. Most likely your MinGW installation is damaged and I suggest reinstalling it. Preferably through a package manager.

My personal go-to solution for installing MinGW is through MSys2 which uses the Pacman package manager (courtesy of Arch Linux); https://msys2.github.io/

Comment: Yup! Looks like there's something weird with MinGW 4.9.2; Just made a clean install from MinGW 5.3 and everything's ok. Thanks =^^=